# Как сделать автоматическое переключение мелодии в js?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

То есть у меня есть плеер, музыку можно по кнопкам переключать, но автоматически она не переключается. Вот сайт: [ссылка](http://f0524651.xsph.ru/)

Comment: Так это не работает. "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей."

Comment: Там бы ещё сделать переключение слайдов и музыки с помощью клавиш со стрелками вправо и влево. Одним словом ещё arbeiten und arbeiten

Answer (score 1):

Автоматическое переключение на следующую песню обеспечивает событие audio.onended. Т.е., индекс массива, в котором хранятся названия песен, url аудиофайлов по этому событию должен увеличиваться на один, и плеер стартировать по новой:

```html
audio.onended = function(){
  index ++;
  this.src = tracklist[index].url;
  this.play();
   // тут ещё код вывода названия песни, оно находится в tracklist[index].name
}
```

В Вашем случае можно сделать, чтобы с окончанием песни слайдер тоже автоматически перелистывался на следующий слайд.